# Storing a vector of pointers to elements of a vector of vector of ints

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

If I have say `std::vector<std::vector<int>> test_vofv` storing a vector of vectors of ints.

I now want to store pointers to various elements (by which I mean the outer vector i.e. `test_vofv[0]`, `test_vofv[1]`) in a separate vector i.e. `std::vector<pointer> vector_of_pointers`.

What should the type "pointer" actually be? Setting it to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>*` isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>*` isn't correct because that would be declaring a pointer to a vector of vectors of integers. Pointer types are read from right to left.

What you want is a vector of pointers. This means a declaration like `std::vector<something*>` where something is what you want to point to. In your case, a vector of pointers to vectors of integers is `std::vector<std::vector<int>*> vector_of_pointers`. You read the outer vector first, then the pointer inside, then whatever the pointer points to.